# 2D vector of structs

Tags: c++

I am making a minesweeper game.
I have 2 two dimensional vectors, one of type int:

```
vector< vector<int> > mineField;
```

which is filled with randomly placed mines (mines = -1) and one of type cell:

```
vector<vector<cell> > mineField;            //actual representation of game board 

struct cell{
     int state;                     //( 0 hidden, 1 revealed, 2 marked) 
     int value;                     //(-1 mine, 0 no surrounding, # > 0 number of surrounding mines)
     bool isMine;
};
```

After evaluating which cells in the int vector do not have mines, and determining how many mines surround that cell; how can I use the cell vector to update each cell after I've determined how many mines surround it.
Thank You!

Comment: This is very confusing terminology, saying that you have a "two-dimensional vector" that is "of type int". No, the vector is a one-dimensional vector of type `vector<vector<int>>` and it stores `vector<int>`s!

Comment: What do you get stuck on when you try it yourself?

Comment: Off topic. Having two variables named `mineField` seems not to be a good idea to me. Even if they don't wander into each other's scope, it makes searching more difficult.

Comment: All the information of `int` `mineField` is also in `cell` `mineField`. You can discard the `int` mineField`.

Comment: You can also make isMine a member function and declare mineField as a vector of Cell (not of vector of Cell). [i][j] becomes [i * columns + j].